# How can I refactor this Makefile to not use fake .out outputs?

Tags: make, gnu-make

I have tests in `tests/FILENAME-test.sh` and for each one I want to run the script inside a docker container.

How can I refactor this Makefile to not use `TEST_OUTPUTS` like I have?

Also, how can I make each `docker run` command run in parallel?

```
.PHONY: test image

TESTS=$(wildcard tests/*-test.sh)
TEST_OUTPUTS=$(patsubst %.sh,%.out,$(TESTS))

%.out: %.sh image
    @sudo docker run -t box-test /bin/bash "-c" "./$^"

test: $(TEST_OUTPUTS)
    @echo

image:
    @sudo docker build -q -t box-test .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
.PHONY: test image

TESTS=$(wildcard tests/*-test.sh)

test: $(TESTS)

$(TESTS): image
        @sudo docker run -t box-test /bin/bash "-c" "./$@"

image:
        @sudo docker build -q -t box-test .
```

And for the `docker run` commands to run in parallel, just use `make -j test` (you may specify a maximum number of concurrent runs with `-j`).